# Mysql trigger syntax (IF NOT EXISTS)

Tags: mysql, sybase

We have two tables ( Club, Village )

```
Club(id, Name, Location, Village)
Village(id, name)
```

Professor gave us example like this...

```
CREATE TRIGGER tg_add_club
AFTER INSERT ON Club
REFERENCING NEW AS uus
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    IF (NOT EXISTS ( 
        )
        THEN 
        )
    END IF;

    UPDATE Club
END;
```

I don't get the syntax idea. I tried to use this example

```
CREATE TRIGGER tg_add_club
AFTER INSERT ON Club
REFERENCING NEW AS uus
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    IF uus.Club.Location (NOT EXISTS ( Village.name 
        )
        THEN INSERT INTO Village (name) VALUES (uus.Club.location)
        )
    END IF;

    UPDATE Club SET (Village.name = uus.Location)
END;
```

Obviously it's not working, it looks more like a pseudocode...but it should give the idea. How can i fix my code ?

If something is not clear, then I will try to add more information

Comment: 'REFERENCING NEW AS uus' is not mysql syntax. If you are using mysql drop this and change other occurrences of uus to NEW and an existence check needs a select

Comment: Whats the error? What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: Are you using MySQL or Sybase? I really doubt they use the same syntax.

Comment: And if  you are using Sybase, which Sybase RDBMS (ASE? IQ? SQLAnywhere? Advantage?) are version are you using?  as others have alluded to, you need to tell us **what** RDBMS product you're using since each product has its own flavor of the SQL language (ie, not all implemented SQL languages are the same)

Answer (score 1):

It's hard to guess what you want since psuedo-code or not the code is nonsense.

some corrections

```
CREATE TRIGGER tg_add_club
AFTER INSERT ON Club
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    IF NOT EXISTS (select 1 from Village where name = new.location THEN 
       INSERT INTO Village (name) VALUES (new.location)
    else
      #UPDATE Club SET (Village.name = uus.Location)
    end if;
END
```

note - This is mysql syntax , there is no referencing clause, you cannot update CLUB, you may need to set delimiters